# SwiftUI Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI9TextFieldVAA4ViewAAMc Xcode 11 beta 3

Tags: swiftui, dyld

I've got a simple SwiftUI-based app I'm working on.  I just have a dozen or so UI elements.  When I try to launch on device, the app aborts with the following:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI9TextFieldVAA4ViewAAMc
```

Build/run environment:

- Xcode 11.0 beta 2 (11M337n)
- macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta (19A501i)
- Device is iPhone XS Max running iOS 13.0 (17A5522f), which is beta 3.

I thought this was something specific to my project, so I created a new one from the template -- so here's how you can reproduce:

```
1.  Open Xcode
2.  File -> New -> Project
3.  From the iOS tab, choose Single View App
4.  Enter a Product Name, and make sure "Use SwiftUI" is checked.
5.  Next, save the project
6.  Build and run
```

Same issue.  There's no additional error output other than the line above.

Comment: The title says you’re on Xcode 11 beta 3 and your question says Xcode 11 beta 2. Which is it?

Comment: Also, can you actually post something we can reproduce? The error is obviously something... wrong? Who knows. Seriously, you've given nobody here anything to be of help.

Comment: Jake and kontiki have the answer!  I thought I had updated to Xcode beta 3, but that was on the other machine.  Thanks for the quick catch!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot run an app compiled with Xcode beta 2, on a device with iOS13 beta 3. Upgrade your Xcode to beta 3 and all should be good.