# Xcode 11 beta Symbol not found

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, ios13

I tried to run exist app on my iPhone iOS 13, but it giving this error

```
> dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI14NavigationLinkVyxGAA4ViewAAMc  
> Referenced from:
> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/946F9332-1B10-4497-B85A-9B88A938DC5C/MovieSwift.app/MovieSwift
> Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI  in
> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/946F9332-1B10-4497-B85A-9B88A938DC5C/MovieSwift.app/MovieSwift
```

Comment: Both Xcode and iOS need to be on the *same* beta version. Are they?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917612/swiftui-symbol-not-found-s7swiftui9textfieldvaa4viewaamc-xcode-11-beta-3/56919338#56919338

Comment: Thank you @dfd I updated the phone version and its working like a charm