# dyld: Symbol not found (Xcode 11)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, swiftui

If i deploy my SwiftUI app to my iPhone 6s i get this error. I don't know why as the app runs fine on the simulator.

> > dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI16PresentationLinkVyxq_GAA4ViewAAMc
> >       Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A285C84-8B0C-4E78-8F5B-474B564898BE/TwitterSwiftUI.app/TwitterSwiftUI
> >       Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
> >      in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A285C84-8B0C-4E78-8F5B-474B564898BE/TwitterSwiftUI.app/TwitterSwiftUI

Comment: Is you iPhone running iOS 13? Same beta as Xcode?

Comment: @dfd Yes it's running the latest one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwiftUI Symbol not found: \_$s7SwiftUI9TextFieldVAA4ViewAAMc Xcode 11 beta 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917612/swiftui-symbol-not-found-s7swiftui9textfieldvaa4viewaamc-xcode-11-beta-3)

Comment: @Celina: Are you sure it's the same issue? In that question it was a "text field".

Comment: It had the same solution, so I figured. But please explain, if you think differently!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please update your Device to the latest version of iOS 13 beta. I was facing the same with different issues such as "SwiftUI Framework Not Found,etc" which occurred even after adding the libraries. I had my IDE with latest Beta and Device on 1st Beta OS. After Updating it worked fine

Comment: I working on Mac no device for update and same problem

Comment: @Nayef have you found a solution for this? I am still struggling finding out where the mistake is to be found.

Comment: For anyone working with iOS 17 betas, in my case the symbol had to do with CKSyncEngine and the difference was that the problematic device had a newer developer beta. I solved the issue by reverting back to iOS 16.6 and then installing the iOS 17 Public Beta, the same as on my other devices that did not have the missing symbol problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have added a framework in your app, you need to add framework search path in build settings.

Comment: for example my framework search path is set to "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/CryptoSwift" both in custom framework using this pod and also the app. But still i see a crash, Any suggestions